# Deploying Yii2 to heroku

Tags: php, heroku, deployment, yii2

I've tried to find a step-by-step tutorial for deploying Yii2 to heroku, but didn't seem to find any. Can someone provide a quick guide for this?

Comment: Would it be different to any other PHP app?

Comment: Actually, it turns out that Yii2 lacking some documentation in terms of production. I've already found answer to all issues that I've had: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259504/setup-yii2-advanced-on-heroku. So I guess, we can vote to close the question.